# Summary function returns Null instead of Max, Min, ect

Tags: r

I have spatial data. I tried to get the summary of it using the `summary` function in R. However, the `summary` function return `Null: the value` instead of the expected output.

Here is part of my data:

```
 # A tibble: 4,319 x 9
      RN    Sd    p  N     Ca    Cl    M        la    lo
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 20923    33  NA   98.9  68.1  109.9 46.2   147.  147.
 2 32233    22   7.9 56    32    45    15     147.  147.
 3 33534    16  NA   78.7  81.5  153   37.2   147.  147.
 4 33979    26  NA   141.6 74.4  181.6 28.6   147.  147.
 5 33979    26  NA   142.5 72.1  184.3 29.2   147.  147.
 6 35098    19  NA   85    26    135   17     147.  147.
 7 35098    18   7.4 155   38    265   31.5   147.  147.
 8 35099    20  NA   150   42    224   25     147.  147.
 9 35153    22   7.8 41    16    53    11     147.  147.
10 35154    22   8.3 137   44    265   28     147.  147. 

 summary(mydata)
```

Part of the output is:

```
        RN                Sd               p           N             Ca            Cl             M        
 Min.   :   20923   Min.   :   0.00   Min.   : 2.200   NULL:98.9      NULL:68.1     NULL:109.9     NULL:46.2    
 1st Qu.:11910081   1st Qu.:  14.00   1st Qu.: 7.500   NULL:56        NULL:32       NULL:45        NULL:15      
 Median :11910270   Median :  21.00   Median : 7.900   NULL:78.7      NULL:81.5     NULL:153       NULL:37.2    
 Mean   :11090548   Mean   :  25.37   Mean   : 7.807   NULL:141.6     NULL:74.4     NULL:181.6     NULL:28.6    
 3rd Qu.:12000148   3rd Qu.:  28.00   3rd Qu.: 8.200   NULL:142.5     NULL:72.1     NULL:184.3     NULL:29.2    
 Max.   :12100518   Max.   :2800.00   Max.   :12.000   NULL:85        NULL:26       NULL:135       NULL:17      
                    NA's   :415       NA's   :21       NULL:155       NULL:38       NULL:265       NULL:31.5
```

If I use `min` or `max` function for `Ca`, I get this:

```
> min(mydata$Ca, na.rm=T)
[1] "0.9"
```

I have no idea why I get this result? any idea or help, please?

Comment: "<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> **<chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>** <dbl> <dbl>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mydata$Ca is a character value

Try:

```
mydata$Ca <- as.numeric(mydata$Ca)
```

first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all of your weird columns are actually characters. Usually `summary` recognizes this. Try restarting your R session and then check why your columns are being read like `characters` (maybe some entry error).